# Awk or sed or others files management tools delete certains lines if found a pattern

Tags: awk, sed, gnu

Hi folks a pleasure to write here. Nice to meet you.

I'm adding some feature to a markdown bash script that translate Markup to XHTML.

I'm searching for this pattern:

```
<p>
<img ...
</p>
```

If found I just want to live the `<img>` line.
How could I do it?

Nice regards,

RG.

Comment: [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858) I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
sed -n '/<img.*/{x;n;d;};1h;1!{x;p;};${x;p;}'
```